# Can't query standard field "Type"

Tags: soql, query, fields

Type is a standard field on the object Account, and also apparently a reserved word in APEX, so how can I write/alter my SOQL query to include data from this field? I found documentation on creating aliases and aggregate expressions, but it didn't really answer my question.

I also need to base if/else statements later on in the trigger on this field, how do I force APEX to treat it like the field it is instead of a reserved word at that time?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share your code ?

Comment: Yes, please share your code. `Select Type From Account` executes fine for me.

Comment: My query: 

List<Account> accounts = [select Id, Account_Domain__c, Type from Account where Account_Domain__C LIKE :wildCard];

I was just informed by a more seasoned dev on my team that although it's on the list of reserved words & highlighted in DEV Console to indicate that, presently writing it this way shouldn't effect anything. 

So I guess the real question is, what happens to the trigger when Salesforce decides to assign value to this word they've reserved?

For now though it sounds like a work-around isn't needed, and I jumped the gun on reacting. 

Thank you for your responses!

Comment: For reference :  

Shows "Type" as reserved for future use:  

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_reserved_words.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SOQL query will look like this:

```
SELECT Type FROM Account
```

So for example when you create and insert an account

```
Account newAcc = new Account();
newAcc.Name = 'Test';
newAcc.Type = 'WhatEverValue';
insert newAcc;
```

In your if statement you will have

```
if(newAcc.Type == 'Your Value'){
    //Code statement
}
```

Or

```
if(String.IsNotEmpty(newAcc.Type)){
   //Code statement
}
```